# use multiple css filters at the same time?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am experimenting with css filters.

And I would like use the blur and grayscale at the same time, but I can't seem to use both simultaneously on the same image?

See fiddle here...

http://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/fw0m9fzu/1/

```
.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

.grayscale {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```
.blur-grayscale {
    filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
    -o-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
}
```

Comment: Doh, just tested it and they now both work. See updated fiddle. Thanks

Comment: You should write that in your own answer and accept that answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Because it's one property  named `filter`, every time you want to add a style to it you override it.

#### CSS version 1

Fortunately you can add multiple styles in some properties like background-image and filter!
To get this working you'll have to put all the filter styles in one space separated filter property.

```
.grayscale.blur {
    filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1);
}
```

#### CSS version 2

An alternative, flexible, solution would be to create a "div soup" on purpose and set different filters in the html stack.
e.g.

```
<div class='demo__blurwrap' style='filter: blur(5px);'>
    <div class="demo__graywrap" style='filter: grayscale(1);'>
        <img src="awesome_image.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS version 3

**edit**: just realised I just wrote this version with transforms, but the same idea applies.

Yet another solution is CSS vars. I wouldn't say it's ideal but it's a nice experiment. The major downside is that you need to declare a lot of variables, have default long rules for `transform` and nested transforms will definitely break.

```js
// Added just for fun
setInterval(() => {
  yes_this_works_and_one_of_many_reasons_ids_are_bad.classList.toggle('translate');
}, 1000);
setInterval(() => {
  yes_this_works_and_one_of_many_reasons_ids_are_bad.classList.toggle('scale');
}, 1500);
```

```css
:root {
  --scale: 1;
  --translate: 0px;
}
.box {
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: 
    scale(var(--scale))
    translate(var(--translate), var(--translate));
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.box.translate {
  --translate: 20px;
}
.box.scale {
  --scale: 3;
}
```

```html
<div 
  id='yes_this_works_and_one_of_many_reasons_ids_are_bad' 
  class='box scale translate'
></div>
```

#### Javascript

Lastly, if you were to use JavaScript to render the styles you can read the current applied filters using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and add more to the mix.

- [Modern browser demo setting styles nicely](https://jsfiddle.net/qgg170rg/)
- [Modern browser demo setting styles without respect and fix it with observers](https://jsfiddle.net/wq11bq9w/)

And a relevant article - this is more for animations and not yet supported by many browsers: [Additive animations](https://css-tricks.com/additive-animation-web-animations-api/)

And another relevant article on css-tricks: [Houdini](https://css-tricks.com/what-houdini-means-for-animating-transforms/)

Comment: Yeah, I like your "Maybe in the future" suggestion, which would be ideal.

Comment: And the same for transforms would be also great :)

Comment: Is this "maybe in the future" section based on anything? Does it come from any sort of proposed addition to the spec? Any proprietary implementation? Or is it just a section of non-relevant musing?

Comment: @JimboJonny It's been a long time since I wrote this answer, if I remember correctly I saw it as a suggestion in some csswg mailing list. But it's probably closest to "non relevant musing"

Comment: Why are properties like `transform` comma separated but `filter` _space_ separated? confusing

Comment: @ElijahMock The usual difference is it either being an actual list (like multiple background images and transforms) or it being 1 property that accept an actual value-set like `margin: 0 1px 3px 0;`. For `background` a combination of both is available. Having only spaces for this would not work. Also, to make it easier to remember, lists are usually not limited in amount and order while value-sets are predefined.

Answer (score 9):

I'm trying to create utility classes in vanilla CSS and this would be helpful but it looks like it can not be done this way.

```
<img class="brightness-20 image-grayscale-100">
.brightness-20 {
    filter:brightness(20%);
}
.image-grayscale-100 {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

I'm not sure why they didn't just create a more specific property like:

```
filter-brightness: 20%; filter-grayscale: 100%
```

After some more work I came up with this solution:

```
/*Initalize Variables No Adjustments*/
:root {
    --blur:0px;
    --contrast:100%;
    --brightness:100%;
    --contrast:100%;
    --dropshadow:0px 0px 0px black;
    --grayscale:0%;
    --hue-rotate:0deg;
    --invert:0%;
    --opacity:100%;
    --saturate:100%;
    --sepia:0%;
}
/*Apply Defult Variables To Image*/
.filter {
    filter: blur(var(--blur)) contrast(var(--contrast)) brightness(var(--brightness)) contrast(var(--contrast)) drop-shadow(var(--dropshadow)) grayscale(var(--grayscale)) hue-rotate(var(--hue-rotate)) invert(var(--invert)) opacity(var(--opacity)) saturate(var(--saturate)) sepia(var(--sepia)); 
}
/*Override Defults*/
.brightness-20 {
    --brightness:20%;
}
.image-grayscale-100 {
    --grayscale: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As this seems to be missing from the **answers** so far and only mentioned in a comment, here is what works:

Simply combine multiple filters separated by space, such as:

```
filter: grayscale() blur(5px);
```

Also see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/81wvj2xf/).

Answer (score 2):

I am using this.

```
/* Multiple filters */
backdrop-filter: url(filters.svg#filter) blur(4px) saturate(150%);
```